# What language is this, file is javascript. <%= %> and how to do a ternary

Tags: javascript, jsp, html-email, email-templates

I am modifying an email template and from what I have seen it may be JSP expression tags.  What I am trying to do is write a ternary for the email template.  I get it partially working with,

```
     <%= data.unitNumber ?  data.unitNumber : " " %>
```

but what I need done is something along the lines of

```
<%= data.unitNumber ?  <span>Unit Number: data.unitNumber</span> : " " %>
```

When I add a tag or a string it no longer works...  any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `<%= data.unitNumber ?  "<span>Unit Number: "+data.unitNumber+"</span>" : " " %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language you are using is [EJS, see here](https://ejs.co/)

If you are trying to display blocks of HTML i would recommend for a simple if else for simple readibility, because EJS syntax is kind of weird. Here's an example.

```
<% if (data.unitNumber) { %>
  <span>Unit Number: <%= data.unitNumber %></span>
<% } else { %>
    <span> User doesnt exist.  </span>
<% }  %>
```

If you want to go for a ternary, check the Ilya Bursov comment